# Equivalence classes on Z

Tags: elementary-number-theory, ring-theory

So I'm given that R is an equivalence relation on Z, and that adding classes in the natural way is well defined. That is, class(a)+class(b) = class(a + b).  I want to show that R can only be equality mod n (for some n) or actual equality.  I'm provided a hint to take into account the smallest difference present between elements of the same equivalence class...I'm pretty stumped unfortunately.

I think I want to find such a minimal difference between elements and show that any other difference between elements in that class is a multiple of the minimal.  The Euclidean algorithm seems relevant to that approach, but methinks I might be entirely misguided...

Comment: I think you are on the right track. Keep going!

Comment: And consider class(0)+class(0)=class(0).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We denote the equivalence relation by $\equiv$.

By the assumption, $a \equiv a'$ and $b \equiv b'$ imply $a + a' \equiv b + b'$.
In particular, $a \equiv a'$ implies $a + b \equiv a' + b$ for every $b \in \mathbb{Z}$. 
Hence $a \equiv 0$ implies $-a \equiv 0$.

Let $I = \{a \in \mathbb{Z}\colon a \equiv 0\}$.
If $I = 0$, then $\equiv$ is clearly equality.
So we suppose $I \neq 0$.
Let $n$ be the least positive integer belonging to $I$.
Let $x \in I$.
$x$ can be written as $x = nq + r$, where $q, r \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $0 \le r < n$.
Since $nq \in I$, $r = x - nq \in I$.
Hence $r = 0$.
Hence $I =  \mathbb{Z}n$.
Therefore the equivalence relation is defined by mod $n$.